# Execute task when new element is inserted into table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Basically, as the title says. I want to send a message to a channel whenever a new element is added to a MySQL table, and I want to get information from the new table.

I have no idea where to start as I'm not so experienced with SQL.

This is what I've got so far!

```
String getBan = "SELECT * FROM bans";
PreparedStatement insert = SQLConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(getBan);

        embed.addField("Punishment Type", "Ban", true);
        embed.addField("ID", insert.executeQuery().getString("id"), true);
        embed.addField("UUID", insert.executeQuery().getString("uuid"), false);
        embed.addField("Banned By", insert.executeQuery().getString("banned_by_name"), true);
        embed.addField("Reason", insert.executeQuery().getString("reason"), true
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looking for a *trigger*.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be trying to find out how I can use that. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How do we use a MySQL trigger to send a message outside of MySQL? Add a user defined function? Write a plug-in? Set up replication and pose as a slave? If there is something simpler I have not seen it. (And have not looked hard, just settled for polling.)